# React not passing props to component

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have just started learning React and trying to pass props down to child component as I have seen in many tutorials & [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).
But I can't see any props passed in my child component.
I have `installed React Developer` Tools in Chrome

My code is as follows:

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Movies from './Components/Movies';
import GetMovies from './Data/MoviesServie';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      movies: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const movies = [...GetMovies()];
    this.setState({ movies });  // 1. setting state
  }

  render() {
    return <Movies movie={this.state.movie} />; // NOT WORKING
  }
}

export default App;
```

I have also tried console logging and found following things are called in sequence

- constructor called ( obviously )
- render
- componentDidMound // here I am setting state but still it is logging blank array
- render ( again render with state is set with array of objects )

But when I see props in `<Movies />` component I didn't see anything there.
Props is null/blank there.

I don't know what is the problem, every tutorial shows the method, which I am using here.

Comment: You're passing `movie` instead of `movies`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed a letter

Change  `return <Movies movie={this.state.movie} />;`

To  `return <Movies movie={this.state.movies} />;`

Comment: I have the same problem. I already check spelling, and it's all correct, but still it pass empty string instead of my expected value. It is only Hello World page tho, i passed it from `ReactDOM.render()` . why is it not passed to the ui? https://jsfiddle.net/y1cmgt0e/1/